# What does the pound sign next to object reference in IntelliJ mean?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, object-reference

What does the pound sign count (highlighted in the screenshot) mean?

[image: Object reference in IntelliJ]

I use IntelliJ 12 Community Edition. The project uses the Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA displays the text returned by the toString() method of the object in question. The pound sign means whatever the author of that method intended it to mean.